# Solution of composition of function

Tags: functions, exponential-function, function-and-relation-composition

In a book I saw a question along with solution

The question is

Let f,g,h be function from R to R , then show that (f+g)oh = (foh).(goh)

But when I saw the solution i got confused , they have cancelled the term x from both sides how ?     [image]

Comment: I don't really understand your confusion. Two functions $u,v:A\to B$  are equal ($u=v$) if and only if $u(x)=v(x)$ for every $x\in A$. In order to prove $u=v$ it is shown that this is indeed the case. You are calling $x$ a "term". You better call it an "argument". Final remark: it is proved here that $(f+g)\circ h=(f\circ h)+(g\circ h)$ (not $(f+g)\circ h=(f\circ h).(g\circ h)$ as you suggest).

Comment: @drhab so how they have cancel the argument x

Comment: If you are saying that $u(x)=v(x)$ then two interpretations are possible: 1) for some **fixed** $x\in A$ it is true that $u(x)=v(x)$. 2) the functions $u$ and $v$ are the same. In 2) the $x$ is looked at as a variable that ranges over the domain. It is less ambiguous to use the expression $u=v$ for that interpretation. This (better) notation is judged by you as "cancelling the argument". You must look at it as: the argument is not relevant anymore, since $u(x)=v(x)$ **for any argument** $x$. Then we leave out the irrelevant $x$.

Comment: Why downvoting this question? The OP is just confused about an important basic fact, and needs some help to get out.

Comment: I think that @koolman does not know what a function actually is and when two functions are equal. If that is the case, then the question itself is not the problem.

Comment: @Epsilon so you can help me out in explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that two functions are identical if they have the same domain (which, in your case, they do) and the same values.

So, all you have to prove is that *for every $x$* in $\mathbb R$, the value $((f+h)\circ h)(x)$ is the same as the value $(f\circ g + g\circ h)(x)$.

There is no "canceling of $x$" anywhere. The proof is a typical proof of a statmenet of the form "for all $x$, $P(x)$ is true":

1. Let $x$ be an arbitrary value of $x\in\mathbb R$.
2. Then, $((f+g)\circ h)(x) = (f+g)(h(x))$ (by definition of compositums)
3. $=f(h(x)) + g(h(x))$ (by the definition of what a sum of functions is)
4. $=(f\circ h)(x) + (g\circ h)(x)$  (again, definition of compositums, used in the other direction)
5. $=((f\circ h) + (g\circ h))(x)$ (by the definition of the sum of functions, used in the other direction)
6. Therefore, we have proven for this value of $x$ that $((f+g)\circ h)(x)=((f\circ h) + (g\circ h))(x)$.
7. Because $x$ was arbitrary, we have proven that the above holds for all values of $x$.
8. Therefore, $(f+g)\circ h=(f\circ h) + (g\circ h)$

Comment: What do you mean by x is arbitrary

Comment: @koolman It means that $x$ can be any real number, in this case. You don't know anything about it. You only know it's a real number.

Comment: In 5 step how they have taken function common

Comment: @koolman For any function $F$ and $G$ and any argument $y$, you know that $(F+G)(y) = F(y) + G(y)$ by definition. Now, set $y=x, F=f\circ h$ and $H=g\circ h$.

Comment: So if u(x) = v(x)    then u=v

Comment: @koolman No. If $u(x)=v(x)$ **for every value of $x$**, then $u=v$. The book you use also tells you this same thing (I know this because it uses this fact in a proof)

Comment: Can you plese give me an example of such type of function

Comment: @koolman Of what type of function?

Comment: of u and v functions

Comment: @koolman I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: if u(x) = v(x) then u=v in this example of u and v

Comment: @koolman I already told you, that isn't true!

Comment: @koolman You are being very sloppy or are on purpose not listening to what I am saying. Please, read my answer again, carefully, and write it down, and try to understand it. It's all very basic.

Comment: sorry i have changes my comment

Comment: @koolman Whatever that's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will clear up some misunderstanding about what you call "cancelling $x$".

---

If you prescribe functions $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto\sin x$ and $v:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto\cos(x-\frac12\pi)$ then: $$u=\{\langle x,\sin x\rangle\mid x\in\mathbb R\}=\{\langle x,\cos(x-\frac12\pi)\rangle\mid x\in\mathbb R\}=v$$

Sometimes this is expressed as $u(x)=v(x)$ where $x$ is looked at as a variable ranging over domain $\mathbb R$. This expression is tricky in the sense that $f(x)=g(x)$ can also be used to express that eventually **distinct** functions $f$ and $g$ take the same value at $x$. In that interpretation $x$ must not be looked at as a variable, but as fixed element of the domain.

Comment: So why in my solution they have taken x in starting

Comment: In order to prove $u=v$ it must be shown that $u(x)=v(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain. That's what is done. In my example to prove that $u=v$ it must be shown that $\sin x=\cos(x-\frac12\pi)$ for every $x$. So also in that case an $x$ in starting.

Comment: in your example u is sin and v is cos am i correct

Comment: In my example $u=\sin$ but $v\neq\cos$. In fact $v$ is defined by $v(x)=\cos(x-\frac12\pi)$. The equality $\sin x=\cos(x-\frac12\pi)$ (true for every $x\in\mathbb R$) then allows us to conclude that $u=v$.

Comment: so what actually v is

Comment: $v$ is a function with domain $\mathbb R$ that is prescribed by $x\mapsto\cos(x-\frac12\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you very much @drhab

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Sorry one more doubt that in this we cannot find the exact value of v

Comment: $v$ is function (not a value) and $v(x)$ is a value for every fixed $x\in\mathbb R$ so there are several values that can be taken by $v$.